# Why does ConfigParser items() give raw strings while get() returns bool/float/etc?

Tags: python, python-2.7, configparser

I'm trying to figure out why ConfigParser is giving Python types for the get() method, but items() is giving all strings, like 'True' instead of True, etc.

As a workaround I'm doing something like this:

```
log_settings = dict(CONF.items('log'))
for key, value in log_settings.items():
    log_settings[key] = CONF.get('log', key)
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: To be clear the  real source of my problem was that I was using a subclass of ConfigParser that overrode the get() function without my realizaton. I was using [code from Spyder](https://bitbucket.org/spyder-ide/spyderlib/src/0df476e899cec2eac10b9c59bfe67ddc4ca1dcf1/spyderlib/userconfig.py?at=default#cl-82) without fully understanding it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `ConfigParser` source:

```
def items(self, section):
    try:
        d2 = self._sections[section]
    except KeyError:
        if section != DEFAULTSECT:
            raise NoSectionError(section)
        d2 = self._dict()
    d = self._defaults.copy()
    d.update(d2)
    if "__name__" in d:
        del d["__name__"]
    return d.items()
```

As you can see, `.items()` does no post-processing of the data to convert it to any type.

---

As a side note, are you sure `.get` isn't doing the same thing?  The source code for `.get` does no coercing of the data, but `.getboolean` and co. do.  Are you sure you aren't using `.getboolean` or `.getfloat`?

Below, you can see there is a helper `._get` function that calls `.get` plus a conversion for the `.getfloat` etc.

```
def _get(self, section, conv, option):
    return conv(self.get(section, option))

def getfloat(self, section, option):
    return self._get(section, float, option)
```

The `.get` function has no such converion (it is done after `.get` in `._get`)

```
def get(self, section, option):
    opt = self.optionxform(option)
    if section not in self._sections:
        if section != DEFAULTSECT:
            raise NoSectionError(section)
        if opt in self._defaults:
            return self._defaults[opt]
        else:
            raise NoOptionError(option, section)
    elif opt in self._sections[section]:
        return self._sections[section][opt]
    elif opt in self._defaults:
        return self._defaults[opt]
    else:
        raise NoOptionError(option, section)
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right ... it turns out that my main problem is that I'm using someone else's code without realizing how it works.  I'm using Spyder as an example for doing configuration management in a PyQt application... well it turns out they subclass ConfigParser and override the get method! [Here it is](https://bitbucket.org/spyder-ide/spyderlib/src/0df476e899cec2eac10b9c59bfe67ddc4ca1dcf1/spyderlib/userconfig.py?at=default).  Looks like they did it to allow complex data to be parsed by eval since they run ConfigParser in raw mode.

Answer (score 0):

While this has already been answered, this was the top stackoverflow result in google for "python configparser .items parse boolean"

So being that i need booleans at the time of parsing, i thought i would share some example code that i'm using.. It of course is simple and only an example.. But might save someone some time or give them ideas..

Also note this is in a class, so ignore the self. if your not using one.

```
self.ConfigManager = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
self.ConfigManager.read('settings.ini')
listConfigSections = self.ConfigManager.sections()
for cfgSection in listConfigSections:
    self.Settings[cfgSection] = {}
    for cfgItem in self.ConfigManager.items(cfgSection):
        if str(cfgItem[1]).lower()=="true":
            self.Settings[cfgSection][cfgItem[0]] = True                    
        elif str(cfgItem[1]).lower()=="false":
            self.Settings[cfgSection][cfgItem[0]] = False                   
        else:
            self.Settings[cfgSection][cfgItem[0]] = cfgItem[1]
```

Anyway, hope it helps someone and please no comments on coding standards.. this is only for display purposes....

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! These days if someone came to me with this kind of problem asking for a recommendation I'd recommend looking at JSON or YAML instead of INI files. Pros and Cons, but I find the better support of hierarchical data desirable. Getting YAML to work with OrderedDict in the way I wanted took some work, but I liked the result.

Comment: Dont get me wrong, JSON is my mainstream method every where. Just existing projects that need updating vs converting.